# Force required to send ball in set trajectory

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, acceleration, projectile

If I have a desired 2D trajectory where I know the desired speed of my ball and desired path, and a ball that starts at (x=0,y=0), how can I calculate the required force / point at which the force should be applied to the ball to produce the desired trajectory?  I've been able to find plenty of information about how to find the launch angle to produce a certain trajectory, but what I think I'm looking for is the force necessary to **produce** a desired launch angle.

Appreciate any insights! The only other forces acting on the ball besides the kick are gravity--we can assume frictionless environment.  The ball's mass and coefficient of restitution are also known.

The ball starts on the ground and is kicked.  Where on the ball should I kick it in order to produce a certain launch angle? Basically how can I kick the ball up, without scooping underneath or having my end effector "foot" come in contact with the ground?

Comment: That force is impulsive. So that force is not constant.

Comment: @manshu: no, not necessarily.

Comment: How is the ball shot? by hand? by cannon? by a baseball bat?

Comment: The ball is kicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Launch force.]

Exert a constant force $F$ pointing from the origin in $(x,y)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$ at angle $\theta$, for a period of time $\Delta t$, so that:

$$F=ma,$$
and:
$$v_1=\frac{F}{m}\Delta t$$

Choose the angle $\theta$ so that $\vec{v_1}$ is tangential at $(x_1,y_1)$ to your trajectory $y=f(x)$ (I assume other forces will then take over, hence the curvature).

If it makes things easier, you can later skip from one coordinate system to the other, e.g.:

$$x'=x-x_1$$
$$y'=y-y_1$$

---

**Edit:** (in response to OP's edit to the question)

The initial velocity and angle of launch of the ball could be simply modelled as follows, see diagram below:

[image: Kicking a ball.]

Some assumptions need to be made:

1. The kicker hits the ball at height above the horizontal $h (<R)$ and the speed vector $\vec{v}$ of the shoe is purely horizontal with magnitude $v$.
2. No momentum is lost by the shoe: we consider it much more massive than the ball itself.
3. The collision is free of friction.

Due to assumption 2. the situation now becomes equivalent (simply change frame of reference) to the ball falling onto a stationary shoe with speed $v_b$ and rebounding.

$v_b$ is the radial component of $\vec{v}$ and is simply (in scalar form):

$$v_b=v\cos\theta,$$

and from simple trigonometry we can derive:

$$\tan\theta=\frac{R-h}{\sqrt{R^2-(R-h)^2}}.$$

If a restitution coefficient $r$ needs to be taken into account, then:

$$v_b=vr\cos\theta$$

Note also that with $y=f(x)$ the trajectory's function, then:

$$\tan\theta=\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)_{x_1}=y'(x_1).$$

Comment: This definitely makes sense if I could come up from underneath the ball! Sorry, I'm not sure my original question was clear, but the ball is resting on the ground so I can only contact it in the height range y=0 to y=2*radius of ball.  Is there a way to do this where the force is coming in from a range between the bottom of the ball (without touching the ground), and the top of the ball?

Comment: @EricaFischer-Colbrie: Hi. With the edit made it becomes rather a different question. Give me some time to try an come up with a solution.

Comment: @EricaFischer-Colbrie: edit made.

Comment: thank you so much! This is hugely helpful and absolutely gets to what I was looking for. Appreciate the clear and detailed description.

Comment: @EricaFischer-Colbrie: welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by saying that you know the desired speed you mean the real initial velocity which is the sum of two vector components in X and Y direction. To throw a ball first generally you need to pull it backward and then apply force on it till the moment you release it. Now start the calculation from right after the moment you pulled the ball. The ball's initial velocity (Vi) is 0 and the velocity at just before the moment you release the ball, in other words, your "desired velocity" is Vf. And the displacement is the distance over which you pulled (s)
Now the formula is (Vf)^2=(Vi)^2 + 2as
You know the value of Vf, Vi and s. Find out the acceleration 'a' from the equation. Then put it in this equation F= ma. Were F is the force. m is mass and a is the acceleration. The value of F is going to be the force you need to exert

Comment: It is not that easy. the ball moves in a curve when we apply force to it in by our hand. If the trajectory was linear, it could be right.

Answer (score 0):

So the motion is the trajectory of a ball with math $m$ thrown with the initial velocity $v_0$.
And you want the initial force.

As you see in the equation of motion of a thrown mass, there is no initial force but an initial velocity. because it is theoretic.

In reality you can't achieve a velocity in 0 seconds, so there is a initial trajectory that gives the final velocity to the ball when it is thrown.

assuming the trajectory as an arc of a circle with the radius $r$ which is more realistic.

and assuming you are trying your best and applying the maximum force you can.

so we have an angular acceleration $\alpha$ witch indicates your max arm muscles' strength.

And you are using only your shoulder muscles (to be simpler).

[image: ball]

We know that:

$$\vec\alpha = \vec r \times \vec a$$

and:

$$\alpha = r a$$

also:

$$v_f=at+v_i$$

so we get to ($v_i=0$):

$$v_f = \frac{\alpha t}{r}$$

So it depends on you arm length and you angular acceleration given to the ball.

Answer (score 0):

Don't look for the desired force insted look for the desired velocity.

Lets consider that you have the desired path which would be parabolic in nature. You can find the path or the quadratic equation by fitting a curve in the following data of coordinates

So you come up with a equation starts from (0,0) and ends at (x,y)
$$y=ax^2+bx+c$$
What you can do is compare the coefficient of this equation
$$y=x\tan \theta-\frac{gx^2}{2u^2}(1+\tan ^2\theta)$$
$$y=-\frac{gx^2}{2u^2}(1+\tan ^2\theta)+x\tan \theta+c$$
This the equation of the trajectory with $u\to\text{ initial velocity}$ and $\theta\to\text{the angle of launch with respect to x axis of earth}$

[image: how to apply the equation]
Now it is important to note that $x,y$ are the coordinates of the last desired position.
Now I hope that this will help to find the initial velocity and the angle of release easily. no need to apply unnecessary calculus